# Аккордеон через slideToggle штормит, туда-сюда открывается\закрывается

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

При нажатии **slideToggle** штормит, содержимое открывается\закрывается туда-сюда. Не понимаю, что не так

JS:

```
$('.filter__item-drop').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('filter__item-drop--active');
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: По ссылке 404 ошибка :(

Comment: Вот поэтому и не надо публиковать сторонние ссылки, а весь код прикладывать к вопросу. Потому что ссылка может стать неактуальной по разным причинам и ваш вопрос потеряет ценность.

Answer (score 0):

Пофиксила, нужно добавить функцию **.stop()**

```
$('.filter__item-drop').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('filter__item-drop--active');
    $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
});
```